# How to parse JSON array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am new to php programming. Here in my project I am trying to parse JSON data coming from php web service. Here is the code in web service.

```
$query = "select * from tableA where ID = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $arr= array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $arr['articles'][] = $row;
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
else{
    echo "No Names";
}
```

This is giving me data in this JSON format.

```
{"articles":[{"ID":"1","Title":"Welcome","Content":"This is the first article."}]}
```

Now here is my php page code.

```
<?php
$jfile = file_get_contents('http://localhost/api/get_content.php');
$final_res = json_decode($jfile, true) ;
var_dump( $final_res );
$content = $final_res->articles->Content;
?>
```

I want to show the content on webpage.

I know code at `var_dump( $final_res );` is working. But after that code is wrong. I tried to look at many tutorials to find the solution but didn't find anyone. I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: RTM: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with `true`: _returned objects will be converted into associative arrays._. Right now (with `true`), you'd access data like so: `echo $final_res['articles'][0]['Title'];`

Comment: Yes i did it. But i am stuck how to retrieve the JSON Content key value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second parameter of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) determines whether to return the result as an array instead of an object. Since you set it to true your result is an array and not an object.

```
$content = $final_res['articles'][0]['Content'];
```

Comment: this will explains you more in details: https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative answer, if you want to use it as an object, use this code:

```
$a = '{"articles":[{"ID":"1","Title":"Welcome","Content":"This is the first article."}]}';
$final_res = json_decode($a);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($final_res);
echo '</pre><br>';
```

*Note that I removed the second part (true) from the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)*
Output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [articles] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [Title] => Welcome
                    [Content] => This is the first article.
                )

        )

)
```

Accessing `Content`:

```
echo 'Content: ' . $final_res->articles[0]->Content;
```

Output:

```
Content: This is the first article.
```

[Run code](https://3v4l.org/q8jlQ)

Comment: If I updated content value and push into json's back, how should we do this?

Comment: file_put_contents($path, json_encode($data['articles'])) , I am using this code, but its remove article array, o/p is stdClass Object, why?
(
    Array([0] => stdClass Object(
                    [ID] => 1
                    [Title] => Welcome
                    [Content] => This is the updated article.
                )

        )

)

Comment: @latikas I suggest you open another question, it's nearly impossible and discouraged to try to solve an issue through comments.