# Split a JSON that contains an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am retrieving a JSON from a URL using `file_get_contents($url);`
The JSON that I am retrieving is in this form:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "Dave",
        "age" : 20,
        "sex" : "M"
    },
    {
        "name" : "John",
        "age" : 31,
        "sex" : "M"

    },
    {
        "name" : "Jane",
        "age" : 24,
        "sex" : "F"
    }   
]
```

How do I access the information? I have been trying to use `json_decode($json, true)` but it really doesn't give the desired outcome.

I am looking to end up with an **array of objects**, so that I would be able to do:

```
$some_array[1]->name
// John
$some_array[2]->age
// 24
```

Comment: json_decode($json, false). http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: There are thousands of _How can I parse json with php_ questions on StackOverflow.   Please research, search, and read the manual before posting a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON array of objects in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481541/how-to-parse-json-array-of-objects-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `json_decode($json, true)` will give you an associative array as result. That means you will be able to access the data with `$decoded[0]['name']` for example. If you omit the second parameter on `json_decode`, you will get what you are looking for:

```
$json = '[
    {
        "name" : "Dave",
        "age" : 20,
        "sex" : "M"
    },
    {
        "name" : "John",
        "age" : 31,
        "sex" : "M"

    },
    {
        "name" : "Jane",
        "age" : 24,
        "sex" : "F"
    }   
]';

$data = json_decode($json); // default for 2nd parameter is false
var_dump($data);
```

produces the following output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Dave"
    ["age"]=>
    int(20)
    ["sex"]=>
    string(1) "M"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
    ["age"]=>
    int(31)
    ["sex"]=>
    string(1) "M"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Jane"
    ["age"]=>
    int(24)
    ["sex"]=>
    string(1) "F"
  }
}
```

Be aware that the objects in the result are not of any special type. So your IDE most likely will have no idea what attributes are available. Therefore you will also not get any type-hinting for them.